# With use of change() and show(), drop down list selection is not shown on android chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

On the selecting a value from a drop down list, I wan't another hidden element to show up.
I'm using the following code:

```js
$('#ddd').change(function() {
 $("#divoption237").show(300);
});
```

```html
<div id="option236" class="option"> 
  <select id="ddd"  value="236" name="option[236]">
    <option value=""> --- Selecteer --- </option>
    <option data-id="49" value="40">Hond</option>
    <option data-id="50" value="41">Kat</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This all works fine in firefox, chrome and IE on my desktop. However I've run into some weird problem on my android phone in chrome. Whenever I select a value, for example Hond, it won't show up as being picked. So the user will still see -- Selecteer -- on his/her screen. The value is selected however and will be send if the form is sent. If I change show(300) to show(), the value is shown to the user. I'd like to use the animation though. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nothing happens when I select an option.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense. You calling `.show` on the container element of the select. Why are you doing this? If the user can use the select, then container is already visible.

Comment: Correct me if I made a mistake in the code above, but I call it on #divoption237, that's not the container element of the select, that's #option236.